# How to install mongoshell of MongoDB 4.4.0 image in docker container?

Tags: mongodb, docker, mongo-shell

I am trying to use MongoDB 4.4.0 in a Virtual Machine. In the image mongosh cannot be accessed with mongosh command. How can I access my database from the container?

wget -qO - https://www.mongodb.org/static/pgp/server-6.0.asc | sudo apt-key add -
sudo apt-get install wget

Tried this commands. Didn't seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

```
apt-get update

apt-get install wget

wget -qO - https://www.mongodb.org/static/pgp/server-6.0.asc | apt-key add -

echo "deb [ arch=amd64,arm64 ] https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu bionic/mongodb-org/6.0 multiverse" | tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-6.0.list

apt-get install -y mongodb-mongosh
```

After all these commands, `mongosh` finally ran. Docker doesn't allow to use the `sudo` command.